# How to update single record in multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

.NET MVC. Actually I got a little issue while updating record. Let me explain you my concern. I have entered some stock item and saved in the database. And on the basis of that I have created Purchase Order. If I want to change any stock item name. I want that change would be reflect in my purchase order details where that stock item is used. Let me share you my code.

```
 [Table("Stock")]
public partial class Stock
{
    [Key]
    public int Stock_ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string LoginID { get; set; }
    public string Stock_Name { get; set; }
    public string Stock_UOM { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }
}

public class StockViewModel
{
    public int Stock_ID { get; set; }
    public string LoginID { get; set; }
    public string Stock_Name { get; set; }
    public string Stock_UOM { get; set; }
}

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStock(StockViewModel stock)
    {
        Stock stock2 = new Stock();

        string loginId = Convert.ToString(Session["LoginId"]);
        string UserRoleName = Convert.ToString(Session["UserTypeName"]);
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginId))
            {
                if (UserRoleName == RoleTypeConstant.CustomerUserType)
                {

                    stock2 = context.Stocks.Where(x => x.Stock_ID == stock.Stock_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (stock2 != null)
                    {
                        using (var txn = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                stock2.Stock_Name = stock.Stock_Name;
                                stock2.Stock_UOM = stock.Stock_UOM;

                                List<OrderDetail> order = new List<OrderDetail>();
                                foreach (var item in order)
                                {
                                    var orderlist = context.OrderDetails.Where(x => x.ProductID == stock.Stock_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (orderlist != null)
                                    {
                                        orderlist.ProductName = stock.Stock_Name;
                                    }
                                }
                                context.SaveChanges();
                                txn.Commit();
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                txn.Rollback();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stock = new StockViewModel();
                    return RedirectToAction("GetEditStockPartial");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("SKU", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Please help me in this. I really thankful to you.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Without digging too much in your code, based on your post title it sounds like you need to create a one to many relationship between the tables. So updating 1 table with reflect on its relational tables.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Then you should instead post your db model, you need to create primary and foreign keys in the tables to create the relations.

Comment: I have updated one screenshot just look into that please.

Comment: Let me explain you my exact concern. I am dealing in stock items and i have created a table for that and all the items are saved in that. On the basis of that i have created some  of the Purchase Orders. Now if i change any of my stock item name. I want that change will reflect on my all purchase orders. For doing this i have added ProductID in OrderDetails Table.

Comment: You need to create a stock_fk column in your orderdetail table. This will hold the stockId that relates to the stock table. Then when updating (or selecting) your records be sure to include a join to the 2 tables;
where orderdetail.stock_fk = stock.stock_id

Comment: Can you provide me a code for this please.

Comment: What's your Stock constructor/class look like?

Comment: I have updated some of the code in my query. Please check there

Comment: Looks to me like your class should include both the orderdetsils and stock info, then in your where clause you can join the 2 on the ID and Fk fields.

Comment: Can you please provide me any example. So that i can do that.

Comment: Just update your class to include all the fields from both tables, then see what your where clause returns.  Is this homework?

Comment: So you are saying i need to add both table fields in one viewmodel. Am i correct?

Comment: yes try that...